# Toggle() Won't Cycle Between Provided Texts

Tags: jquery

Test website here: http://pomonabeta.comeze.com/

I have a slideshow that users have requested be optional. I have a button that will hide the slideshow or show it. Here is the code:

```
    //hiding and showing the slideshow
$('#show_hide_button').click(function(){
    $('.fluid_container').slideToggle();
    $('#show_hide_button').toggle(
    function(){
    $('#show_hide_button').text("Show the slideshow");
    },
    function(){
    $('#show_hide_button').text("Hide the slideshow");
    });

});
```

*(document).ready is implemented*

The slideshow hides and shows successfully. **Problem**: The text changes to "Show the slideshow" and stays in that state. Toggle seems not to be working properly. Could you find the error in my coding?

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: 1.8.3 is my current version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    //hiding and showing the slideshow
$('#show_hide_button').click(function(){
    $('.fluid_container').slideToggle();

//this will set the text to whichever it is not already
    $('#show_hide_button').text(function (index, text) {
        return (text == "Show the slideshow" ? "Hide the slideshow" : "Show the slideshow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I would buy you a beer if I had money, knew which bar you went to, and was of age. But I would just like to know something quick, when you call the throwaway function, you call for two variables, index and test. Where does the function get these variables and what are their values?

Comment: they are built into the jquery .text() function, they are the index position of the element in the set, and the current text value: http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text , and thanks for the hypothetical beer!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest :

```
$('#show_hide_button').click(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $('.fluid_container').slideToggle();

    if($this.hasClass('showed')){
      $('#show_hide_button').text('Hide..');
      $this.removeClass('showed');
     }
    else {
      $('#show_hide_button').text('show..');
      $this.addClass('showed');        
    }
});
```

Comment: I think @mr_lewjam is more fluid as it has less code and less processes. Though this does work, I agree. Thanks though!

Comment: You're welcome. I posted this solution because I think that statement on entire string could provide problems, but is also a good solution!  See ya!